# JDBC with H2 and MySQL mode: create procedure fails

Tags: java, stored-procedures, jdbc, h2

## Description of code

### Database connection

I try to to store Java object locally database without use external database.
For this I use JDBC with H2 via Hibernate :

```
    /**
     * @param connection the connection to set
     */
    public static void setConnectionHibernate() {
        Properties connectionProps = new Properties();
        connectionProps.put("user", "sa");
        try {
            Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        url = "jdbc:h2:mem:db1;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MODE=MySQL;";
    }
```

### Query

I store the PROCEDURE in String with this code :

```
    static final String CREATE_PROCEDURE_INITPSEUDOS = "CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE init_pseudos (MaxPseudo INT) BEGIN WHILE MaxPseudo >= 0 DO"
            +
            " INSERT INTO Pseudos (indexPseudo)" +
            " VALUES (MaxPseudo);" +
            " SET MaxPseudo = MaxPseudo - 1;" +
            " END WHILE;" +
            " END init_pseudos;";
```

### Query execution

And I execute the statement with this code :

```
    public static void initBaseDonneePseudos() {
        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, connectionProps);
                Statement stmt = connection.createStatement()) {
            stmt.execute(RequetesSQL.CREATE_TABLE_PSEUDOS);
            stmt.execute(RequetesSQL.CREATE_PROCEDURE_INITPSEUDOS);
            stmt.execute(RequetesSQL.CREATE_FUNCTION_RECUPEREPSEUDO);
            stmt.execute(RequetesSQL.INIT_TABLE_PSEUDOS);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

## Problem

### Test

I execute this test to test statement :

```
    @Nested
    class BaseDonneeInteractionTest {

        @BeforeEach
        public void setUp() {
            BaseDonnee.setConnectionHibernate();
        }

        @Test
        void testInitBaseDonnee() {
            assertDoesNotThrow(() -> BaseDonnee.initBaseDonneePseudos());
        }

    }
```

### Error

But I obtain this error

[image]

I didn't find the problem of the query, anybody have the solution to solve this ?

Comment: You should post the error message as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "MySQL Compatibility Mode" doesn't make H2 100% compatible with MySQL. It just changes a few things. The [documentation](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility) lists them:

- Creating indexes in the CREATE TABLE statement is allowed using INDEX(..) or KEY(..). Example: create table test(id int primary key, name varchar(255), key idx_name(name));
- When converting a floating point number to an integer, the fractional digits are not truncated, but the value is rounded.
- ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE is supported in INSERT statements, due to this feature VALUES has special non-standard meaning is some contexts.
- INSERT IGNORE is partially supported and may be used to skip rows with duplicate keys if ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE is not specified.
- REPLACE INTO is partially supported.
- Spaces are trimmed from the right side of CHAR values.
- REGEXP_REPLACE() uses \ for back-references.
- Datetime value functions return the same value within a command.
- 0x literals are parsed as binary string literals.
- Unrelated expressions in ORDER BY clause of DISTINCT queries are allowed.
- Some MySQL-specific ALTER TABLE commands are partially supported.
- TRUNCATE TABLE restarts next values of generated columns.
- If value of an identity column was manually specified, its sequence is updated to generate values after inserted.
- NULL value works like DEFAULT value is assignments to identity columns.
- Referential constraints don't require an existing primary key or unique constraint on referenced columns and create a unique constraint automatically if such constraint doesn't exist.
- LIMIT / OFFSET clauses are supported.
- AUTO_INCREMENT clause can be used.
- YEAR data type is treated like SMALLINT data type.
- GROUP BY clause can contain 1-based positions of expressions from the SELECT list.
- Unsafe comparison operators between numeric and boolean values are allowed.

That's all. There is nothing about procedures. As @jccampanero pointed out in the other answer, you must use the syntax specific to H2 if you want to create stored procedures.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in H2 there are not explicit procedures or functions as you are trying defining.

For that purpose, H2 allows you to create used defined functions instead. Please, consider reed the appropriate [documentation](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#user_defined_functions).

Basically, you create a user defined function by declaring an `ALIAS` for a bunch of Java code.

For example, in your use case, your `CREATE_PROCEDURE_INITPSEUDOS` could look similar to this:

```
CREATE ALIAS INIT_PSEUDOS AS  $$
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
@CODE
void init_pseudos(final Connection conn, final int maxPseudo) throws SQLException {
  try (Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()) {
    while (maxPseudo >= 0) do {
      stmt.execute("INSERT INTO Pseudos (indexPseudo)  VALUES (MaxPseudo);");
      maxPseudo = maxPseudo - 1;
    }
  }
}
$$;
```

Note the following:

- As I said, you define a user defined function as Java code. That Java code should be enclosed between two `$$` delimiters.
- Although I included explicitly some imports, you can use any class in the `java.util` or `java.sql` packages in your code. If you want to included explicitly some imports, or if you require classes from other packages than the mentioned, the corresponding imports should be provided right after the first `$$` token. In addition, you need to include `@CODE` the signal H2 where your imports end and your actual Java method starts.
- If you need a reference to a `Connection` to the database in your code, it should be the first argument of your method.
- Prefer to raise and not hide exceptions: it will allow your transactions to be committed or rollbacked as a whole appropriately.

You can invoke such a function as usual:

```
CALL INIT_PSEUDOS (5);
```

Please, provide the appropriate value for the `maxPseudo` argument.

Please, consider the provided code as just an example of use: you can improve the code in different ways, like using `PreparedStatement`s instead of `Statement`s for efficiency purposes, checking parameters for nullability, etcetera.

Answer (score 1):

#### Using H2 as a test database product

Historically, H2 has been used a lot as a test replacement for the actual production database product. But this means you're limiting yourself to the least common denominator between H2 and MySQL, in your case. Including, as others pointed out, the lack of support for stored procedures. You could re-implement all the stored procedures in H2 (very tedious and error prone), or, you could just use [testcontainers](https://testcontainers.org) and run actual integration tests on MySQL directly.

I really think that using H2 as an integration test database is an outdated concept [as I've shown in this blog post](https://blog.jooq.org/using-h2-as-a-test-database-product/) (unless you're also using H2 in production). You'll be much happier developing and testing everything against MySQL directly!

#### Using recursive SQL instead

You don't really need that procedure, I think? You probably wrote it to avoid too many round trips to the database for that loop. But you could batch the inserts or generate the following recursive SQL:

```sql
INSERT INTO Pseudos (indexPseudo)
WITH RECURSIVE
  p (i) AS (
    SELECT MaxPseudo
    UNION ALL
    SELECT i - 1 FROM p WHERE i >= 0
  )
SELECT i FROM p;
```

Now there's no more need to place this in a procedure, you can run the query directly.

#### Translating your procedure to H2

Just to be complete, for translation of simple procedural logic, [jOOQ would offer the feature transparently](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/parsing-connection/). [You can try it online, here](https://www.jooq.org/translate/). It's probably overkill, I recommend the other approaches, but perhaps worth a try.

Disclaimer: I work for the company behind jOOQ.